# How to get the total number of elements in a HTML with Selenium WebDriver and Autohotkey?

Tags: javascript, selenium, autohotkey

I am trying to get the total number of items in an HTML page by a given class. I am using Selenium and Autohotkey to do it

I've searched a lot of this topic but haven't found my particular solution

Most of suggestions and answers I researched included solutions but for Java or other language, not for Autohotkey (Although they have similar structures in this case)

Using this code to work with:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="pancakes">
            <button class="button">Blueberry</button><br><br>
            <button class="button">Banana</button><br><br>
            <button class="button">Strawberry</button><br><br>
            <button class="button">Yumi</button><br><br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For getting the text from a element by class it can be done by this:

```
driver.findElementByClass("button").Attribute("innerText")
```

*Output: Blueberry*

Now, for getting a certain item of a class using Xpath, is as follows:

```
driver.findElementsByXpath("//*[contains(@id,'pancakes')]/button").item[1].Attribute("innerText")
```

*Output: Strawberry*

What I need is to get the total number of "buttons". So I need an **output** that gives me "**4**" (since there is **4 "buttons"**)

I havent find a way to do this in Autohotkey. I've seen solutions for other languages like

A

```
len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a'))
```

B

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form1']/div[4]"));

//Get list of table elements using tagName
List<WebElement> list = webElement.findElements(By.tagName("table"));
```

C

```
IList<IWebElement> selectElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));

foreach (IWebElement select in selectElements)
{
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(select);
    Console.WriteLine(selectElement.SelectedOption.Text);
}
```

and more but this doesn't work with Autohokey because of those functions and variables (like len(), IList, and others)

I am expecting to **get** just the **total number of items** by any way possible

I am thinking on maybe some function for Selenium I haven't founded yet and I dont know about (like some -at the end of the line- ".len",".size",".count" but non of them worked for me)

Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: wow I was just missing the "**()**" on "**.Count**"

this is what I was looking for

```
driver.findElementsByXpath("//*[contains(@id,'pancakes')]/button").Count()
```

Thanks to supputuri

Comment: Try with `driver.findElementsByXpath("//*[contains(@id,'pancakes')]/button").Count()`.

Comment: DUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUDE IT WORKS!
Thanks! hours and hours of searching this and was it simple as that, I think can't set your answer like the Accepted one here :/

Comment: One more thing, you know where I could find more of that functions/commands I can use (like that ".Count")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Count()` method to get the number of elements matching your xpath.

```
 driver.findElementsByXpath("//*[contains(@id,'pancakes')]/button").Count()
```

you can [refer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Count) to this for more information.