# Selenium and AutoHotkey - How to get the size of table rows/column?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, autohotkey

I've been researching hours without success

I just need the syntax for Autohotkey to get the size of a table rows/column

I am following this guide https://www.guru99.com/handling-dynamic-selenium-webdriver.html

In other languages they suggest this:

```
WebElement tbody = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody"));
List<WebElement> rows = tbody.findElements(By.xpath("tr"));
totalrows = rows.size();
```

Note that they use the "List" to convert into a List type the variable, the problem is, that in AHK there is no variable type definition, it should be automatically, but apparently not in this case

This is the page I am doing test on, but can't get it to work
http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php#

I just need to know how many rows and/or columns it has, it should be as simple as this:

```
 MsgBox %  ""  oChrome.findElementByXpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th").size()
```

(Gives no error but doesnt show any value)

Or even this, like there they suggested ([How to get the total number of elements in a HTML with Selenium WebDriver and Autohotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237659/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-elements-in-a-html-with-selenium-webdriver-and-au))

```
 MsgBox %  ""  oChrome.findElementByXpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th").Count()
```

(Error: Unknown Name, Specifically: Count)

The goals is to have the number of columns (in this case 5) and Rows (26), this, in order to further fo a For Each and loop through the values of each row

I would appreciate any kinds of suggestions, thanks!

Full Code

```
oChrome := ChromeGet() ; Object for Chrome

MsgBox %  ""  oChrome.findElementByXpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th").Size() ; FAIL

MsgBox %  "Finish" 
return

ChromeGet(IP_Port := "127.0.0.1:9222") {
    oChrome := ComObjCreate("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    oChrome.SetCapability("debuggerAddress", IP_Port)
    oChrome.Start()
    return oChrome
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Length` function ? If you define a variable first then get the length of it. Something like this for the columns : `Var := oChrome.findElementByXpath("//table//th")
MsgBox % "" Var.Length()` For the lines without a variable : `MsgBox %  ""  oChrome.findElementByXpath("//table//tr[not(th)]").Length()`

Comment: Didn't work either :( it seems that it has something to do with the functions calls not being recognized or something like that, or a missed class (like when dealing with Selects, there is a part where you have to set ".AsSelect" and so)

Comment: Can you print the text from elements returned by your XPath expression? `Count` function doesn't work anymore?You said it works here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237659/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-elements-in-a-html-with-selenium-webdriver-and-au#comment100977340_57237659 Try to induce "innerText" then Count or Length  : `Var := oChrome.findElementByXpath("//table//th").Attribute("innerText") MsgBox % "" Var.Count()` Also try with another webdriver : `driver:= ComObjCreate("Selenium.CHROMEDriver") ;Chrome driver
driver.Get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php#")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! yeah, it really was a silly thing actually, see me answer, I missed the "s" on "findElementByXpath", and actually, in the stack overflow question there, itt was using indeed "findElementsByXpath" but silly me, thanks!

Comment: Seems logic. Nice catch. I missed it too. Since `findElement` doesn't output a list but a single element, `Count` function returns an error. Duly noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, so, after days of research, I noted a a little bigger thing, I needed to use:

```
.findElementsByXpath()
```

Instead of:

```
.findElementByXpath()
```

I noticed tht when looking in this Selenium documentarion for Python:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Which made me thing on that extra "s" on it, and so, it was that! and also I used Count().
And it falls in a simple logic (and common sense now I realize), findElementsByXpath(), as the docs said, search for multiple element values, not just one, that way you are allowed to use the ".Count()" to search for the total of children in a node for example
So, the end code working for me is the following:

```
oChrome := ChromeGet() ; Object for Chrome

MsgBox %  ""  oChrome.findElementsByXpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/thead/tr/th").Count() 

MsgBox %  "Finish" 
return

ChromeGet(IP_Port := "127.0.0.1:9222") {
    oChrome := ComObjCreate("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    oChrome.SetCapability("debuggerAddress", IP_Port)
    oChrome.Start()
    return oChrome
}
```